# Batch renaming files by PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-prompt

How can I rename files in a folder that have random names and random extensions to a sequence like the example below: 0001.pdf 0002.pdf ..... 0100.png and continue.

And if possible then generate a .txt file with the names and extensions generated.

For the .txt file if not possible Powershel could be another application.

Searching I got the code below, but I can't fix it for the task I need.

`Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace " - ","0" }`

Comment: `[ref]$i = 1; Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { "{0}{1}"-f $i.Value++, $_.Extension } `  should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the call to `Rename-Item` in `ForEach-Object` then maintain a counter in a variable:

```
$fileNumber = 1
Get-ChildItem path\to\folder\containing\random\files -File |ForEach-Object {
    # Construct new file name
    $newName = '{0:0000}{1}' -f $fileNumber,$_.Extension

    # Perform rename
    $_ |Rename-Item -NewName $newName

    # Increment number
    $fileNumber++
}
```

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Worked perfectly.
Is there any application or even powershell that takes these generated files and makes a list in a .txt file with the generated names?

Comment: @kasten you mean after the fact? You can do that fairly easily with `Get-ChildItem path\to\folder\containing\random\files -File |Select -Expand Name |Out-File path\to\inventory.txt`